# Android - Adding button to a listview to show MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, button

I currently have a listview showing a couple of string arrays. I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to add a button to a row in a listview so that when clicked, it loads up the map screen?

My code for the class is follows -

```
class Taxi {
    private String taxiName;
    private String taxiAddress;
    private String taxiDist;

    public String getName() {
        return taxiName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        taxiName = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return taxiAddress;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        taxiAddress = address;
    }
    public String getDist() {
        return taxiDist;
    }
    public void setDist(String dist){
        taxiDist = dist;
    }
    public Taxi(String name, String address, String dist) {
        taxiName = name;
        taxiAddress = address;
        taxiDist = dist;
    }
}

public class TaxiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Taxi> {
    private ArrayList<Taxi> items;
    private TaxiViewHolder taxiHolder;

    private class TaxiViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView address; 
        TextView dist;
    }

    public TaxiAdapter(Context context, int tvResId, ArrayList<Taxi> items) {
        super(context, tvResId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.taxi_list_item, null);
            taxiHolder = new TaxiViewHolder();
            taxiHolder.name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_name);
            taxiHolder.address = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_address);
            taxiHolder.dist = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_dist);
            v.setTag(taxiHolder);
        } else taxiHolder = (TaxiViewHolder)v.getTag(); 

        Taxi taxi = items.get(pos);

        if (taxi != null) {
            taxiHolder.name.setText(taxi.getName());
            taxiHolder.address.setText(taxi.getAddress());
            taxiHolder.dist.setText(taxi.getDist());
        }

        return v;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listtaxi);

    final String[] taxiNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_name_array);
    final String[] taxiAddresses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_address_array);
    final String[] taxiDist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.taxi_array_dist);
    ArrayList<Taxi> taxiList = new ArrayList<Taxi>();

    for (int i = 0; i < taxiNames.length; i++) {
        taxiList.add(new Taxi(taxiNames[i], taxiAddresses[i], taxiDist[i]));

    }


    setListAdapter(new TaxiAdapter(this, R.layout.taxi_list_item, taxiList));  

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id)
        {       

            final int selectedPosition = position;
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListTaxi.this); 
             adb.setTitle("Taxi Booking");
             adb.setMessage("You Have Selected: "+taxiNames[selectedPosition]); 
             adb.setPositiveButton("Book", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(ListTaxi.this, Booking.class);
                     intent.putExtra("booking",  taxiNames[selectedPosition]);
                     intent.putExtra("address",  taxiAddresses[selectedPosition]);
                     intent.putExtra("distance", taxiDist[selectedPosition]);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             });
             adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
             adb.show();
         }
     });



}
```

}

Been trying this all night and have not successfully found a way to accomplish this with my setup

Any ideas or hints would be awesome!

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add your own ListAdapter that can customize the view for each row in the List.  Check out this example:

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Inside your view that defines your row you'll have a Button instead of image.  Then when you inflate the view add your listener to the button from the Adapter.  It's really that easy.